# get input values by there class

Tags: html, angular, forms, dom, angular13

I have a following angular component ts with an ability to add dynamic fields to a form:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Buildcompany} from "../../models/buildcompany.model";
import {BuildcompanyService} from "../../services/buildcompany.service";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-buildcompany',
  templateUrl: './add-buildcompany.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-buildcompany.component.css'],

})
export class AddBuildcompanyComponent implements OnInit {


  buildcompany: Buildcompany={
    shortname:'',
    fullname:'',
    address:'',
    telephone:'',
    website:'',
    sociallinks:'',
    foundationyear:''
  }
  submitted=false;
  @ViewChild('network', {static: true}) networkElement: ElementRef;
 netw?: [];

  constructor(private  buildcompanyService:BuildcompanyService,networkElement: ElementRef) {
    this.networkElement=networkElement;


  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add(){
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    row.innerHTML = `
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="netw" name="network[]" #network class="form-control netw">"`;
    let row2 = document.createElement('div');

    row2.innerHTML = `
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="links[]" class="form-control">"`;

    // @ts-ignore
    document.querySelector('.showInputField').appendChild(row);
    // @ts-ignore

    document.querySelector('.showInputField').appendChild(row2);

  }
  saveBuildcompany(): void {
    // @ts-ignore

    this.netw = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByClassName("netw")).value;

    // @ts-ignore
    console.log(this.netw[0].value);
    const data = {
      shortname: this.buildcompany.shortname,
      fullname: this.buildcompany.fullname,
      address: this.buildcompany.address,
      telephone: this.buildcompany.telephone,
      website: this.buildcompany.website,
      sociallinks: this.buildcompany.sociallinks,
      foundationyear: this.buildcompany.foundationyear

    };
    this.buildcompanyService.create(data)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }
  newBuildcompany(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.buildcompany = {
      shortname: '',
      fullname:'',
      address:'',
      telephone:'',
      website:'',
      foundationyear:''

    };
  }
}
```

Is that posible at all to get values of those dynamicly added fields into an array on save() function? I can see in a console that they are actually shown. The class is called netw. Or what is the best approche to this task?

UPDATE
I tryed to add a formgroup and got the following error

```
Error: 
    ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
    formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
```

Comment: If you use reactive forms and use the FormGroup/FormBuilder you're importing, you can associated the form griup with your form, then use `formGroup.value` to get the current values of the form.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well I tryed. Problem is that form is using *ngmodel on my other fields. Wich error I got I don't remember if honestly. That why I thought if I can get value by class.

Comment: And then I try to use formgroup.value it gives undefined in a console